# Python not interpret True - 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, web2py

I'm working with Web2Py. I'm trying to enable a textbox that isn't seemed to be defined anywhere but somehow appears on the web page.

anyways.

If a user logged in belongs to a certain group, the text box is enabled and the user can write in the textbox. If they are not a member of the group, the textbox is disabled - they can read was previously written but can not type in it.

The code that seems to affect the enabled state is this

```
if __userCanPerformStep(step) and not flow_completed:
    flow_step_forms[step.name].element('textarea')['_rows'] = 5
```

**__userCanPerformStep(step)** is defined as

```
def __userCanPerformStep(step_row):
    if auth.user.id in step_row.target_users:
        return True

    for group_id in step_row.target_groups:
        if db((db.auth_membership.user_id == auth.user.id) & (db.auth_membership.group_id == group_id)).count() > 0:
            return True

    if auth.has_group_membership("systemadmin"):
        return True
    return False
```

**has_group_membership** is defined as

```
def has_group_membership(self, groupname):
        if self.db((self.db.auth_group.id > 0) & (self.db.auth_group.role==groupname)).count() > 0:
            group_id = self.db((self.db.auth_group.id > 0) & (self.db.auth_group.role==groupname)).select().first().id
            return self.has_membership(group_id)

        return False
```

Since *__userCanPerformStep* is used in many places, I created a new method as such:

```
def canAddComment(step_row):
    if auth.has_group_membership_or(["groupA", "groupB", "groupC"]):
            return False
    if auth.user.id in step_row.target_users:
            return False
    return False
```

and **has_group_membership_or** defined as

```
def has_group_membership_or(self, groupnames):
        if self.db((self.db.auth_group.id > 0) & (self.db.auth_group.role.belongs(groupnames))).count() > 0:
            for groupname in groupnames:
                group = self.db((self.db.auth_group.id > 0) & (self.db.auth_group.role==groupname)).select().first()
                if group and self.has_membership(group.id):
                    return True

        return False
```

when I now call the function as part of the IF statement like this:

```
if ( ( canAddComment(step)) and (not flow_completed)):
                flow_step_forms[step.name].element('textarea')['_rows'] = 5
```

and every time a user belongs to one of the groups A,B or C. I get the following error:

**'NoneType' object does not support item assignment**

any hints?? 
**SIDE NOTE** 
I've also forced the function to return False right away, and I don't get any errors. If I force True; I get errors. the forcing is done simply by having the first line of the method be *return True*

Q: how can I make python interpret my function being called to accept the value True? what am I overlooking?

**UPDATE**
Full traceback is 
[image]

Comment: Post the full stack trace. it will tell you what object is `None` and where it is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
None['_rows'] = 5
```

throws

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

So `flow_step_forms[step.name].element('textarea')` returns a `None`, presumably because `flow_step_forms[step.name]` has no element `'textarea'` or the element is set to `None`.

If you need further assistance troubleshooting, please edit your question to include where you set that and I'll edit my answer.